# Is there a way of mocking an API request by default if you are in a test environment using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, testing, service, mocking, behat

I have an API method that is called by clicking a buttom in a form and inside that API method there is a request to another API of another project using guzzle. That works fine.

My problem is I'm doing behat tests and I want to test my API method, but I need to mock the request to the external API (because I don't need to test it). Is there any way Laravel detects if I am in a test environment and mock the request and if I'm in a normal environment leave it without mock?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a file in your project called phpunit.xml and you can set the APP_ENV there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     ...
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
<testsuites>

    ... 

    <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<php>
<!-- HERE -->
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

Then you can use whatever logic you like with `if(env('APP_ENV') == 'testing')`

Comment: I tried but APP_ENV doesn't return 'testing' when i execute my behat test (still returning the value from .env). Maybe this only works with phpunit tests?

Comment: @GaroLuis Neve used it, but this might help.  https://github.com/laracasts/Behat-Laravel-Extension-Example-App/blob/master/.env.behat

Comment: I was trying that right know. I added .env.behat to behat.yml and changed APP_ENV and nothing. Then I tried to create a different variable "TEST_MODE" false in .env and true in .env.behat but still reading .env